# SchemaModel.SqlSpatialIndex: Timeout expired

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2014, database-project

I am receiving a timeout error when trying to reverse engineer a SQL Server database into a Database project.  We don't have any spatial indexes on the that database (I checked [using this](http://raresql.com/2013/03/29/sql-server-list-of-all-indexes-with-column-name-and-datatype-including-columnstore-index/)).

I don't have a timeout setting on the connection (

```
3/8/2016 9:46:00 AM An error was received from SQL Server while attempting to reverse engineer elements of type Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SchemaModel.SqlSpatialIndex: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
3/8/2016 9:46:00 AM An exception was generated.
Unable to reconnect to database: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
3/8/2016 9:46:00 AM An error was received from SQL Server while attempting to reverse engineer elements of type Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SchemaModel.SqlSpatialIndex: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
3/8/2016 9:46:00 AM Finished importing database.
3/8/2016 9:46:00 AM A summary of the import was saved to the following location: C:\Temp\Import From Prod 2\Import Schema Logs\Import From Prod 2_20160308024125.log
3/8/2016 9:46:00 AM Click Finish to continue...
```

Steps to reproduce the issue:

1. Open Visual Studio 2013
2. From the menu, click on "View" / "Sql Server Object Explorer"
3. Connect to a SQL Server (in our case, the UAT server) and choose a database
4. From the context menu of the database, choose "Create New Project"
5. Press "Start"

How do I figure out what is actually timing out? How do I fix this?

Comment: Is there anything useful in "C:\Temp\Import From Prod 2\Import Schema Logs\Import From Prod 2_20160308024125.log"?

Answer (score 0):

Can you increase the amount of available RAM? This exact error started showing up for me with schema comparisons between an existing db project and a local database.  The problem was resolved when I shut down all of my applications except Visual Studio.  This makes me think that my pc did not have enough resources to complete the task in the desired time when I have several apps open.

Answer (score 0):

One option that worked for me was to increase the value of HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\NN.N\SQLDB\Database\QueryTimeoutSeconds and restart Visual Studio based on [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlblog/2014/11/13/timeout-expired-while-publishing-to-sql-database-via-ssdt/).  But, although successful, it was taking nearly 5 minutes to compare.

Later I discovered that we recently changed our build target to Sql Server 2016, but were still referencing a 2012 master.dacpac.  I updated the reference to a 2016 master.dacpac and the compare now completes in less than a minute.